# Development Server Failing to see CSS Files | Django

Tags: python, django, development

Right, being a Python & Django student using VSC so therefore, in the interest of not having a nervous breakdown here, how on earth do other VSC users import CSS files into their HTML/PHP documentation?

**This is clear a server issue (hence why this is being posted here and not Stack Overflow) because as far as I'm concerned, my code is correct.**

1. Created a HTML document with the filename `base.html` and added `{% load static %}` at the top of said document. I have then created a HTML document & added `{% extends 'base.html' %}` at the top.
2. Created a `static` folder in the root directory, a sub-director folder of `css` and created a CSS document with the filename `main.css`
3. Went into the Settings, added `STATICFILES_DIR = [BASE_DIR / "static"]` and confirmed that `STATIC_URL = "static/"` was present
4. Confirmed base & path directory as `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`
5. With all this confirmed, I went into the HTML document and uploaded the stylesheet in the following manner `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">` which can be seen when I go to inspect the document from the browser.

However, despite all this, the server is still completely ignoring any CSS documentation, as a test, I have set the `<body>` tag to a different `background-color` and low and behold. I don't see a single shade of blue.

I'm genuinely at a loss as to how - despite following the documentation to the letter - I get a different result. As I started earlier, its clearly a server issue because unless I'm going crazy (which is hardly surprising considering I have to work with VSC) I fail to see what I'm doing wrong here.

[Path Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeIsK.png)

[HTML Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMV7i.png)

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9soDq.png)

[Python Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPP7h.png)

Comment: `This is clear a server issue` - It is not. It's a development environment and therefore off topic. You can post it on SO once your suspension ends.